# What's the reason for this specific "rm" sequence in the xkcd joke?

Tags: rm, command

Here's part of [this xkcd comic strip](http://xkcd.com/1185/) where the idea is that the author can't write a sort program so he adds code to delete all files

```
system("rm -rf ./");
system("rm -rf ~/*");
system("rm -rf /");
```

AFAIK the canonical way to delete everything is to `rm` `/` so that everything starting from root is deleted. Here this is the last command and the two commands before that try to `rm` the current directory and the contents of the home directory.

Why not just `rm` `/`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you start at the very top, it's possible that you'll wipe out something that `rm` (or some other critical part of the system) needs to continue, and the evilness will be left incomplete.

These commands will make sure that at least the cwd and the user's home directory are gone before going nuclear.

Comment: JFTR as rm is loaded in the memor it should work and keep working even if necessary variables are removed. After you run `rm -rf /` from an interactive session your shell should be still working

Comment: Recent `rm`s will fail on the last command with `rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on ‘/’`; other than that `rm` doesn't require access to any resource after initialization. A reason for using multiple commands might be that the user might have different access permissions to those directories.

Comment: @UlrichDangel, I found out the hard way on Solaris a long time back...

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez- Recent versions It will fail like that even with the -f flag?

Comment: It will. You actually need to use `rm --no-preserve-root /` for this to actually work

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Not everyone runs gnu rm. :-)

Comment: "These commands will make sure that at least the cwd and the user's home directory are gone before going nuclear." What if we run that script when we are in "/bin/" :) ? Last two commands will not run at all.

Answer (score 8):

Just to show increasing levels of destructiveness: Delete the current directory, then `$HOME`, finally destroy all.